# When hovering over parent li make child li color white and vice versa

Tags: jquery, html, css

First let me describe the problem I'm having. Please visit http://dev.eduantech.com/about-me to know what I'm talking about. Has to be a page, can't be home page so that you can see what I'm talking about.

OK so please hover over the menu, at least the one that has a sub-menu in it. You will notice that when you hover over the parent `li` the child `li` becomes "invisible", since it's the same color as the background. Vice-versa if you hover over the child element.

What I need to figure out, I'm sure you already guessed, is whenever the mouse is on top of either of these it makes the other one white as well.

I have the following sorta pseudo-code worked out:

```
$('li.menu-parent-current > li.menu-child-current a').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#fdfdfd');
    }, function() {
        if (/* mouse leaves parent as well */) {
            // change child color to blue
        } else if (/* mouse did not leave parent */) {
            // make child color white
            $(this).css('color', '#fdfdfd');
        }
    });
```

There's room for improvement on this, no doubt, so go ahead and give a better version if necessary. :)

I've been the past couple of hours on this but I can't solve it, I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm no jQuery expert. Thanks for the help you can provide. :)

**EDIT:**

Well... Turns out I was over complicating it. Being a relative newbie doesn't let you think correctly. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with CSS and jQuery.

If you will to do that with CSS:

```
li:hover a{color:#fff;}
li:hover ul li a{color:#fff;}
```

And if you want to do that with jQuery:

```
$('ul li').hover(
  function(){$(this).find('a').css('color','#fff');},
  function(){$(this).find('a').css('color','##36c');}
);
```

Comment: That's a very good answer, keep up the good work. :) I was gonna say new guy but I didn't want to sound arrogant. :P Thanks to everyone else that provided an answer as well! However this was the cleanest so thank you all. :)

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm missing something, jquery is overkill here. Simple css is sufficient:

```
li:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

The child `li` inherits the colors from the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Jz9a/

Answer (score 2):

You should be capable of doing this with just CSS instead of also using jQuery's ".hover()".  However, your existing CSS already has some conflicting `:hover` styling that does not play nicely with the doubled-up jQuery `.hover()` behavior.

I would start by cleaning up the CSS and if you have to use jQuery, then at least you'll have a cleaner slate.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
#menu li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following simple css addition

```
#menu li:hover a{
  color: #FDFDFD;
}
```

Hope it will help